# Selecting a number of siblings in jQuery

Tags: jquery

When a user clicks on a `<td>` in a table, I want to apply a css class to it. I also want to apply a css class to its siblings and apply another css class to the last sibling. The following code will achieve this...

```
$('td.sel').addClass('first').siblings().addClass(‘middle').last().addClass('last’);
```

But what I want to do is apply the css class to a particular number of siblings - **not all of them**.

For example, if I had the following table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-num="3">monday</td>
        <td data-num="2">tuesday</td>
        <td data-num="3">wednesday</td>
        <td data-num="2">thursday</td>
        <td data-num="1">friday</td>
        <td data-num="3">saturday</td>
        <td data-num="1">sunday</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

…and if a user clicks the `<td>` with Wednesday then...

1. Add the class ".first" to the clicked `<td>`
2. With the `data-num` value, count the next siblings to apply the class ".middle" to.  `var numberOfDays = $(this).attr("data-num");`
3. Add a different class to the last ".last" sibling

So the table would now look like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-num="3">Monday</td>
        <td data-num="2">Tuesday</td>
        <td data-num="3" class="first" >Wednesday</td>
        <td data-num="2" class="middle">Thursday</td>
        <td data-num="1" class="middle">Friday</td>
        <td data-num="3" class="last" >Saturday</td>
        <td data-num="1">Sunday</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Any advise or help on how to do this is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I created a JSFiddle demonstrating what I am trying to do. It actually works, but the code is poor. I would also need to check if its the very last `<td>` in the table, then apply the .last class. https://jsfiddle.net/5to9hewo/109/

Comment: `<td data-num="3" class="first >` You forgot to close the attribute.

Comment: `$(this).addClass('first').nextAll().not(':last').addClass('middle');` And add class `last` to the last `td`. But what you expect if last td is clicked???  And btw, your posted HTML markup has many wrong characters...

Comment: Paveen - Fixed, thank you. A. Wolff - hmmm good question! I may need then to check if its the last of type in the <tr> and apply it to the next row somehow.

Comment: @Josethehose I'm quite confused about what is your expecting result. Could you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) replicating your issue **and** with complete example of what you are expecting as result?!

Comment: @ A. Wolff - ok, I'll get a fiddle to demo what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible alternative is to keep the days, `slice` the days following the index, without the index itself and then slice all but the last to add the `middle` class. This way, the last element itself will not be affected, and by using `last` on the first object, the last actually existing object will be used:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5to9hewo/114/)

```
var days = $("td.day").click(function() { //assign days and attach the click in one go
  days.removeClass('first last middle');  

  var start = days.index(this),
    end = start + parseFloat($(this).addClass('first').data("num")) ,
    next =  days.slice(++start,end); 
  next.slice(0,end-start-1).addClass('middle');
  next.last().addClass('last');
});
```